# jQuery .height() doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page on which I want the div's that stand next to each other have equal height.

I have the following function:

```
function setProjectsHeight() {
    var count = 0;
    $(".project").each(function() {
        if(count % 3 === 0) { 
            var highest = 0;
            for(i=count;i<=count+2;i++) {
                if($("div.project#"+i).height() > highest) { 
                    highest = $("div.project#"+i).height(); 
                }
            }
            console.log(highest);
        }
        count++;
    });
}
```

Somehow the height is always zero. The selector seems to be right (tested that) and when console.log() the width with the same selector, it returns 200 (correct).

**EDIT: Just solved it!**
Somehow I had the idea to set "body {display:none}" in the css and set this property back to 'block' at the end of document.ready(). I did this because I use jQuery UI buttons and users saw those buttons switch from a normal link to the UI lay-out.

When I removed this functionality, everything worked again. It seems when setProjectsHeight() was called, body was still display:block. Thus, there was no calculated height.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How about posting the HTML you're using this on?

Comment: make sure that at the time of execution, the divs are rendered. but a debugger inside of the each() call to check it out.

Comment: @Hersheezy: jep, that seemed to be the problem (I described it above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it! Somehow I had the idea to set "body {display:none}" in the css and set this property back to 'block' at the end of document.ready(). I did this because I use jQuery UI buttons and users saw those buttons switch from a normal link to the UI lay-out.

When I removed this functionality, everything worked again. It seems when setProjectsHeight() was called, body was still display:block. Thus, there was no calculated height.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try calling that function from the window.load() event instead of document.ready().

The reason for this issue, is that jQuery doesn’t initiate the width() and height() settings until all the img/object/... elements have finished loading - ready() fires as soon as the page has been processed, but some objects may still be downloading at that point.

Comment: I think the problem has indeed something to do with this. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have an element that clears the float / apply a clearfix (if anything is floated). if you don't do this, at least the parent container is not expanded to the height it should have.

Also try to use `.outerHeight()` because this includes border sizes and paddings.

Comment: Already doing this :) But it's fixed now, thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

your selector might be wrong. you should just use the id selector by itself, since ids are unique in the document and have the fastest lookup:

```
$('#'+i)
```

also as people have mentioned, its not valid to have an id start with a number (but works in most browsers)

its also possible that you might have duplicate ids in your DOM, in which case nothing will work as you expect. **dom ids must be unique**.

Comment: This wasn't the problem, but anyway, thanks for your input. Greatly appreciated! I'll update the id's so they validate.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure every `.project` element has the appropriate ID attribute as well, since the `$("div.project#"+i)` selector expects an ID of 0, 1, 2, etc.?

Comment: Yes, it definitely is correct. The problem had to do with something else (see question, solved now)

Answer (score 0):

If tag ids are `1, 2, 3` then please give space after project

```
$("div.project #"+i)
```

Comment: its possible that his html is `<div class='project' id='1'>`